# How to disable Spring AOP at runtime?

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP in my application to log some information at runtime before and after a method call. I have enabled the Spring AOP using annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy.

Everything works fine now, however I wonder if there is a way to disable this at runtime. I googled around a lot but came up with nothing.

Comment: Disable Spring AOP or disable the logging that was added with Spring AOP?

Comment: Disabling AOP is better. Worst case even if there is a way to disable logging at runtime, it is fine too.

Comment: I don't think disabling AOP at runtime is possible. With logging it may be possible with a custom solution to manipulate the logging settings via JMX.

Comment: @MFIhsan did you find a solution here ?